# Known Intersecting Polygons returning false for .intersects() in geopandas

Tags: python, geopandas

I have 2 geodataframes:

1. An original shapefile of water features read in as a geodataframe. (playas)
2. A gdf as a result of a convex_hull operation with only polygon geometries. (polygons)

There should be intersection between these two layers, but the following code returns an empty geodataframe:

```
aff_playas = playas[playas.intersects(polygons)]
```

I am trying to think of what the problem could be with these two layers. I believe it is one of the following:

- A projection inconsistency with the created hulls_gdf
- function failure due to how detailed, varied the playas layer is.

The two layers plotted below have similar extent and are verified to intersect in Qgis, ArcGIS. The third is the output from the intersects().

[image: hulls, plotted]

[image: Playas, plotted]

[image: Intersection visible in Qgis]

Comment: Good idea to check the projections of the both layers. Add the result to your question.

Comment: I added some more information about my code in the question, and I checked the crs for both layers and the seem to be consistent.

Comment: Doesn't "Intersects" return a boolean value? What do you expect to get as a sum of Trues and Falses?

Comment: Good point, the following code also returns no results:  **aff_playas = playas[playas.intersects(polygons)]**

Comment: What is the variable "polygons" in your script? I ask because you refer to the hulls as hulls_gdf but you write "polygons" in your code. How are you checking the CRS and what are the epsgs? If you type "hulls_gdf['geometry'][0]" does it plot the expected geometry of the first polygon in the gdf? (I'm assuming you're using an IDE) @user30184 If you intersect two geodataframes, you get a geodataframe as an output. Not clear if OP is intersecting geometries or geodataframes.

Comment: Ah, I guess you're using shapely's intersects method. You could try     int_gdf = gpd.sjoin(hulls_gdf, water_gdf, op='intersects').

Comment: This is the one. @Jon I posted my workaround with this below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem. For some reason intersects() was not working between my two layers, even though they are shown to intersect. Here is my workaround:

```
sj = gpd.sjoin(playas, polygons, how='inner',op='intersects')
aff_playas = playas.geom_almost_equals(sj)
aff_playas = aff_playas[~aff_playas.index.duplicated()]
playa_subset = playas[aff_playas]
```

Since I couldn't get intersects() to work, I used spatial join and the geom_almost_equals function to subset the original layer to the same intended affect.

Answer (score 1):

`geopandas`'s `.intersects` works by comparing the two geodataframes based on the index values. It's an element wise comparison. If you want to compare **1** shape (eg: convex hull) against all the features, you can use your code as is, but you need to ensure that polygons is a shapely object (for example: union all the geoms to one multipolygon shapely object)

Comment: Please give a code sample and describe your solution more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Below code work for me.

```
sj = gpd.sjoin(filter_street, buffer_project_dataframe, how='inner',op='intersects')
```

But make sure that, buffer_project_dataframe should be a geodataframe, geosereis is not working